# Updating a temporary table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to update a temporary table then query it in a later statement but I don't seem to be having any look. Below is the code I am using:

```
    $updatepostgrad = "UPDATE t1 
                   SET AssociatedModule = 'COMP102' 
                   ORDER BY StudentRanking DESC
                   LIMIT $numberofstudents";

    $perform9 = mysql_query($updatepostgrad);
```

To update the temporary table. Then to query it I use the code below:

```
    $qry15 = "SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE AssociatedModule = 'COMP102'";

    $result15 = mysql_query($qry15);
```

Obviously the table was created successfully early on in the code. When I use

```
    var_dump($result15);
```

to try and gather information all I get is bool(false). Any ideas whats going wrong.
In case it helps the idea of querying the table is to perform the below:

```
while ($return4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result15)) {
$id = $return4['ID'];
$qry15 = "UPDATE postgraduate SET AssociatedModule = 'COMP102' WHERE ID = '$id'"; 
$perform15 = mysql_query($qry15);
```

Comment: How are you creating your temporary table? Are you trying to update/query it on the same connection? Temporary tables only exist for the connection they were created on.

Comment: Use mysql_error() to figure out what the error of the query response when making a stack overflow question about it!!!!